# integer solutions for $\left( a+\sqrt{b} \right) ^ n=p+q\sqrt{b}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given whole numbers $a$, $b$, and $n$, where $\sqrt{b} \not\in \mathbb{N}$, there should be a unique solution where $p$ and $q$ are also whole numbers.   Is there any way of expressing $p$ and $q$ in a closed form using $a$, $b$, and $n$?

Comment: You need the additional assumption that $b$ is square free, otherwise $p$ and $q$ are not unique, for example $(1 + \sqrt{4})^2 = 1 + 4 \sqrt{4} = 3 + 3 \sqrt{4}$.

Comment: Thank you.   I have adjusted the wording of the question above to correspond with this requirement.

Comment: Mark, square free means that, not only is $b$ not a square, but $b$ has no square divisors larger than $1.$ Put another way, it means that the prime factorization of $b$ consists of distinct primes, all exponents equal to one.

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand why.  Could you explain this, please, or please give an example of where there could be a non-unique solution?  If b is not square, then its square root is irrational, and if  difference between any whole multiples of some given number is a whole number, then that number would have to be rational, wouldn't it?

Comment: @WillJagy I should have written `not a square` rather than `square free`. Both are sufficient conditions for the statement to hold, but `square free` is unnecessarily strong. Mark is right, and all that's needed is $\sqrt b \not \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: You’re merely finding the $n$-th power of a given element of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt b]$? I’d just use the Binomial expansion—should be perfectly straightforward.

Comment: For the uniqueness, suppose that there are two distinct solutions; then $p_1+q_1\sqrt{b}=p_2+q_2\sqrt{b}$.  Try subtracting e.g. $p_2+q_1\sqrt{b}$ from both sides of this equation; can you derive a contradiction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New approach: First let's prove inductively that there exist integers that satisfy this equality without worrying about expressing them strictly in terms of $n,a,b$. For the base case of $n=1$ it is obvious that $a = p$ and $q = 1$. In the induction step let's assume there exist integers $p_k, q_k$ such that $(a+\sqrt{b})^k = p_k+q_k\sqrt{b}$ for some $k \geq 1$. Then $$\begin{align}(a+\sqrt{b})^{k+1} &= (a+\sqrt{b})^{k}(a+\sqrt{b})\\ &= (p_k+q_k\sqrt{b})(a+\sqrt{b}) \\ &= ap_k+aq_k\sqrt{b}+p_k\sqrt{b} + q_kb \\ &= (ap_k+q_kb)+(aq_k+p_k)\sqrt{b}\end{align}$$ It is clear that $(ap_k+q_kb),(aq_k+p_k)$ are integers. Let $p_{k+1} = ap_k+q_kb$ and $q_{k+1} = aq_k+p_k$. You now have recursive definitions for the  constants you seek that can be found in terms of $n, a$ and $b$. A computer could instantly calculate these values once you provide the proper algorithm with your initial $a,b$ and designated $n$. More generally, can you work with these equations and see if you can extract a closed-form solution? Up to the case of $n = 3$ the numbers I'm getting for $p, q$ look like they lend themselves to a pattern. Taking a few more cases of $n>3$ to see a pattern, plus another little proof could get you what you want.

Comment: That $p$ is not (guaranteed to be) a whole number.

Comment: You could always group odd powers of $\sqrt{b}$ into $q$, since the even powers $\sqrt{b}^{2 j}$ are known to be whole numbers.

Comment: @Mark Please see the revised answer. It doesn't complete the proof you're looking for but I feel that it's better than my first answer.

Comment: @dxiv My new answer should guarantee that $p_k$ is a whole number

Comment: So now what I need to do is solve the system of two recurrence relations.   $p_{k+1}=a p_k+b q_k, q_{k+1}=a q_k+p_{k}, p_{1}=a, q_{1}=1$.   I'll have to give this some thought.

Comment: @Mark yes, this is at one possible path to an answer. Playing around with the recurrence equations I believe I've found that $q_{k+1}-p_k = aq_k$. Hopefully that is helpful in some way

Comment: @Mark any luck? I think I've successfully decoupled the equations so it should be solveable.